# How can i give alternating row background color and alternating column background color to the listview in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listview, background

And also i want to color the background of headers.
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You need to set up a style with the AlternationIndex set. [This page](http://blogs.mscommunity.net/blogs/borissevo/archive/2008/10/21/wpf-trick-1-alternate-background-colors-for-listview-rows.aspx) gives an example

(defining the style)

```
<Style x:Key="CustomListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2C2C2C"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#262626"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

(using the defined style)

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CustomListViewItemStyle}"
          AlternationCount="2">
    ...
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
' Snipet demonstrating how to alternate colors per N rows of DataGrid using code (VB.Net without Xaml). Uses .Net 3.5 feature of AlternationIndex, AlternationCount
' Assumes DataGrid1 is defined in Window1
' Alternation can be on any size (row count)
       Dim BackgroundStyle As New Style
        BackgroundStyle.TargetType = GetType(DataGridRow)
        For i As Integer = 1 To alternationRows
            Dim tr As New Trigger
            tr.Property = ItemsControl.AlternationIndexProperty
            tr.Value = i - 1
            Dim st As New Setter
            st.Property = BackgroundProperty
            st.Value = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(CByte(&HFF - i * 8), CByte(&HFF - i * 8), CByte(&HFF - i * 8)))
            tr.Setters.Add(st)
            BackgroundStyle.Triggers.Add(tr)
        Next
        DataGrid1.ItemContainerStyle = BackgroundStyle
        DataGrid1.AlternationCount = BackgroundStyle.Triggers.Count
```