# WPF ListView Styling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've only started using the WPF ListView now and I have a few questions:

- Is there a way for me to apply a style where every second row is a bit darker, just for readability?
- What is the ListView equivelant for Width="*"?
- Where can I find a decent looking style?

Thanx

Comment: 1) http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/how-to-set-wpf-listview-alternate-row.html

Comment: 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257500/c-sharp-listview-column-width-auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your questions have been answered previously here:

- [How can i give alternating row background color and alternating column background color to the listview in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399102/how-can-i-give-alternating-row-background-color-and-alternating-column-backgroun#1399119)
- [ListView column auto sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834971/listview-column-auto-sizing)
- [Any free WPF themes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260098/any-free-wpf-themes#260416)

Comment: Any idea how I can add vertical grid lines after each column using a style?

Comment: You could use the GridLinesVisibility property:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.gridlinesvisibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: There is no such property on ListView or GridViewColumn.

Comment: Oops, my fault, you could either start using the DataGrid instead of the ListView or do it like this: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/12/16/wpf-listview-vertical-lines-horizontal-as-bonus.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1-  Check out the AlternationCount property on the ListView.  It allows alternate rows to be styled differently.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount.aspx

It seems someone has answered a similiar question here:
[wpf datagrid alternate row coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792628/wpf-datagrid-alternate-row-coloring)

2- If your looking to size the ListBox to the container try looking at some of the layout containers like at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans). Specifically the DockPanel.

3- [Where can I find free WPF controls and control templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121724/where-can-i-find-free-wpf-controls-and-control-templates)

Answer (score 0):

A few seconds of googling will give you results like[WPF ListView](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/listview-in-wpf/)

and [WPF Listview customize](http://ligao101.wordpress.com/2007/07/27/customizing-listview-in-wpf-part-i/)

and with your second question

"*" means stretch to fill the available space, and is a fraction, so if one row is * and the other row is 2* then the second row will be twice the size of the first row.

Hope it helps